# Selection in Edit Mode not working

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools, shortcut

I was doing a lot of different things in Blender recently and I could select verts with C, B and right mouse button. Now, it is not working anymore. Not even selecting edges or faces. Just the whole object by A. 
I guess I must have pressed any key that locks it by accident. 
I was doing some UV changes, some Mesh deformation and was tweaking things in texture paint mode. I cannot really say where it happened but somewhere later after the mesh changes were applied. 
Hope anyone got a clue what to do.

**EDIT: I was streaming with OBS again and it happened again! I closed and re-opened both programs a few times, selected different .blend files and the problem still occurs. Closed everything, re-started blender first. I then switched to xSplit and it appeared again...**

Have no idea how this could help but here a picture explaination. Added a cube to the current file.

[image]

 Console information added. [image]

Comment: Did so. Have still no idea how to explain without a video or similar.

Comment: Can you attach the .blend?  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I can do but I don't know if it's too large to find the error. I got several ones in the console already. (And they're not connected to this one I think)

Comment: File too large... 455 MiB... :/

Comment: It could be interesting to see if an error or a warning appears in the console. With Linux, start a terminal and type `blender`. On Windows, click the Toogle System console option in the Windows menu (or maybe in the Help menu). Add a screenshot of the console on your post.

Comment: Maybe you change something in the user preferences... Try to click *Load factory settings* in the File menu.

Comment: Okay, I really don't know what happened. I had closed and restarted the engine several times without any change.
Now I just started my computer session as usual and started blender to toggle the console. Went to a different layer and selected an object. As expected I thought vert selection wouldn't work. But it did. I am now completely confused about what exactly happened and why it is normal again. If it occurs again, I will inform again... Thanks everyone for trying to help. I will add the console output nevertheless.

Comment: What are OBS and xSplit? If that happens with just a cube then you can upload the file, chances are though that there's something on your side, like with drivers or operating system. Include infomration about what OS do you use, what graphic card, did you update drivers for it, what programs do you use aside from Blender and upload the file on blend-exchange (see above).

Comment: OBS and xSplit are both sharingware. Means livestream programs. 
I got currently Win 10. Someone recently checked over my hardware and told me that my graphics card is too old. NVIDIA GeForce GT 610. Have got 8 GB RAM. I now succeeded streaming several hours without any more problems about the selection. It must be somewhere where I select modifiers or change material settings. (At least I can think of those two as possible reasons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it was the issue with a setting in the software I use to stream my work. Check if you have got anything like "Multi-Adapt-Compatibility" activated on the selected Blender source in that program. **Deactivate** it. 
Restart both programs and check if it works.